# Counting all 'drawing objects' on stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, count

I have a little problem with counting **all** elements on stage. Flash, unfortunately is counting all objects on the stage without drawn objects (all shapes, including drawing objects, rectangles etc) all missed. Is there any way to count them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the end goal simply counting them or is there more to it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I need to count them and put in array to use them later.

Comment: In that case you can consider using graphics.copyFrom(), http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to drawing primitives, such as lines and circles, then no, there is no way.  You can only address and modify the container (Shape, Sprite, MovieClip, etc.), but once a primitive vector element is drawn, you lose any reference to it.  You can only modify bitmap data.

You could, however create your own class and keep a counter for all those elements that the Flash Player doesn't recognize - just increase the count whenever something is drawn and reset on `Graphics.clear()`.

Comment: lol, I guess we read the question at exactly the same time :)

Comment: So, the only way to count them is converting them to symbols, yeah?

Comment: You have a more technical answer than mine. +1UP

Comment: @Chev No, you don't have to convert to symbols.  You can clear and redraw the graphics when something changes.  But you have to find a way to reference the data for all drawing primitives, perhaps a Vector of custom objects? Then you just do all the drawing again, using the values you've stored.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing as `graphics.numChildren` like there is with MovieClip, [see docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html).

The closests alternative would be to manually keep track of the number of items drawn whenever you draw them either via array/vector or a simple incremental integer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all the objects(Mc's, Graphics's...etc.)
2. Make a new file.
3. Paste the object into the stage
4. Right click and select....Distributes to layers.
5. Check the number of the layers displayed.

I am sure this is how I found the number of leaves in the tree(in my project).

Comment: This seems like a bit over kill but could work for simple situations. However I think the OP wants to also store them in an array.